# SQL Server calculate market share for year, quarter and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to calculate the market share for the sample data below for the month, quarter and year using SQL? 
I can do this in excel just unsure on how to do this in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblReturns](
[ReturnID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerID] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Brand] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Type] [varchar] (100) NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Datecreated] [datetime] NULL)
GO
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 1, '1 sep 2018')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 4, '2 sep 2018')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Can', 4, '10 sep 2018')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Fanta', 'Bottle', 1, '18 sep 2018')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Fanta', 'Can', 4, '1 Oct 2018')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 2, '9 Oct 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Fanta', 'Can', 6, '14 oct 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Fanta', 'Can', 1, '30 oct 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 3, '2 dec 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 8, '3 dec 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Coke', 'Bottle', 8, '3 dec 2017')
 INSERT INTO tblReturns (CustomerID,Brand,Type,Quantity,Datecreated)VALUES  (123, 'Fanta', 'Bottle', 5, '10 dec 2017')
 GO

  SELECT DateCreated
  ,CustomerID
  ,Product
  ,sum(Quantity) as Quantity
  ,DATENAME(MM,DateCreated) as Month
  ,DATENAME(QUARTER, DateCreated) as quarter
  ,DATENAME(yyyy, DateCreated) as Year
   FROM tblReturns
   GROUP BY
  DateCreated
  ,CustomerID
  ,Product
  ,DATENAME(MM,DateCreated)
  ,DATENAME(QUARTER, DateCreated)
  ,DATENAME(yyyy, DateCreated)
  order by DateCreated
```

I need to show the marketshare in percentage for each field Month, Quarter and Year.

expected result below

```
+-------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------+
| Datecreated | CustomerID | Brand |  Type  | Quantity |   Month   | Quarter | Year | %Month  | %Quarter | %Year  |
+-------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------+
| 9/10/2017   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        2 | October   |       4 | 2017 | 22.22%  | 63.64%   | 63.64% |
| 14/10/2017  |        123 | Fanta | Can    |        6 | October   |       4 | 2017 | 77.78%  | 36.36%   | 36.36% |
| 30/10/2017  |        123 | Fanta | Can    |        1 | October   |       4 | 2017 | 77.78%  | 36.36%   | 36.36% |
| 2/12/2017   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        3 | December  |       4 | 2017 | 79.17%  | 63.64%   | 63.64% |
| 3/12/2017   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        8 | December  |       4 | 2017 | 79.17%  | 63.64%   | 63.64% |
| 3/12/2017   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        8 | December  |       4 | 2017 | 79.17%  | 63.64%   | 63.64% |
| 10/12/2017  |        123 | Fanta | Bottle |        5 | December  |       4 | 2017 | 20.83%  | 36.36%   | 36.36% |
| 1/09/2018   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        1 | September |       3 | 2018 | 90.00%  | 90.00%   | 64.29% |
| 2/09/2018   |        123 | Coke  | Bottle |        4 | September |       3 | 2018 | 90.00%  | 90.00%   | 64.29% |
| 10/09/2018  |        123 | Coke  | Can    |        4 | September |       3 | 2018 | 90.00%  | 90.00%   | 64.29% |
| 18/09/2018  |        123 | Fanta | Bottle |        1 | September |       3 | 2018 | 10.00%  | 10.00%   | 35.71% |
| 1/10/2018   |        123 | Fanta | Can    |        4 | October   |       4 | 2018 | 100.00% | 100.00%  | 35.71% |
+-------------+------------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Thanks everyone the below worked perfectly!

```
select r.*,DATENAME(MM,DateCreated) as Month
  ,DATENAME(QUARTER, DateCreated) as quarter
  ,DATENAME(yyyy, DateCreated) as Year
   ,round((sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated), month(datecreated))* 100.0 /
    (sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated), month(datecreated)))),2) as ms_month

   ,round((sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated), datepart(quarter, datecreated)) * 100.0 /
    (sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated), datepart(quarter, datecreated)))),2) as ms_quarter

    ,round((sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated)) * 100.0 /
    (sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated)))),2) as ms_year
from tblreturns r
order by r.DateCreated
```

Comment: Please explain the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear how you are defining market share, but the answer to your question is window functions.

I might interpret market share as the proportion of the brand over all sales for the given unit of time.  If so:

```
select r.*,
       (sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated), month(datecreated) * 1.0 /
        sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated), month(datecreated)
       ) as ms_month,
       (sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated), datepart(quarter, datecreated) * 1.0 /
        sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated), datepart(quarter, datecreated)
       ) as ms_quarter,
       (sum(quantity) over (partition by brand, year(datecreated) * 1.0 /
        sum(quantity) over (partition by year(datecreated)
       ) as ms_year
from tblreturns r;
```

Comment: Thank you with some minor modifications this worked perfectly!